# Multiple leaf node disable in Angular Treel Control

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I am using [angular-tree-control](http://wix.github.io/angular-tree-control), in this I want to know, how to disable multiple leaf nodes? [Here in docs](http://wix.github.io/angular-tree-control/#isSelectable) it says to return `node.label.indexOf("Node 1") !== 0` in `isSelectable` option of tree control, but how can I add multiple leaf nodes here?

I have created a [plunker here](https://plnkr.co/edit/538VpL4OtkhNDyXg3eSP?p=preview).

Tree control option

```
$scope.opts = {
    dirSelectable: false,
    multiSelection: true,
    injectClasses: {
      "li": "injectedTreeLi"
    },
    isSelectable: function(node) {
      // I want to disable 'Info' and 'Debug'
      return node.label.indexOf("Info") !== 0;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
isSelectable: function(node) {
  // I want to disable 'Info' and 'Debug'
  var tmp = node.label.indexOf("Info") !== 0&&node.label.indexOf("Debug") !== 0
  return tmp;
}
```